# Flutter IOS app doesn't receive shared pdf

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, pdf, share

I have a Flutter application and i implemented the package receive_sharing_intent in order to receive shared pdf files in the app. It works perfect in Android. The problem comes in IOS. When i try to share a pdf from the files of the system, my app does appear in the list of apps. But, when i select it, **it doesn't even open**. Here's the configuration i made on the IOS project, based on the package repository here https://github.com/Thogsit/receive_sharing_intent

**Flutter: pubspec.yaml**

[image]

**Runner/info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Business Cards Manager</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>business_cards_manager</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Needed to access location always when the app is open.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Needed to access location when the app is open and run in background.</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>AppGroupId</key>
    <string>$(CUSTOM_GROUP_ID)</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>ShareMedia-$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Share Extension / info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
    <key>AppGroupId</key>
        <string>$(CUSTOM_GROUP_ID)</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>NSExtension</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                <dict>
                    <!--TODO: Add this flag, if you want to support sharing other files into your app-->
                    <!--Change the integer to however many files you want to be able to share at a time-->
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
            <string>MainInterface</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Share Extension/ ShareViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices
import Photos

class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    
    var hostAppBundleIdentifier = ""
    var appGroupId = ""
    let sharedKey = "ShareKey"
    var sharedMedia: [SharedMediaFile] = []
    var sharedText: [String] = []
    let fileURLType = kUTTypeFileURL as String;

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return true
    }
    
    private func loadIds() {
        // loading Share extension App Id
        let shareExtensionAppBundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!;


        // convert ShareExtension id to host app id
        // By default it is remove last part of id after last point
        // For example: com.test.ShareExtension -> com.test
        let lastIndexOfPoint = shareExtensionAppBundleIdentifier.lastIndex(of: ".");
        hostAppBundleIdentifier = String(shareExtensionAppBundleIdentifier[..<lastIndexOfPoint!]);

        // loading custom AppGroupId from Build Settings or use group.<hostAppBundleIdentifier>
        appGroupId = (Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "AppGroupId") as? String) ?? "group.\(hostAppBundleIdentifier)";
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        
        //load group and app id from build info
        loadIds();
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
        if let content = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem {
            if let contents = content.attachments {
                for (index, attachment) in (contents).enumerated() {
                    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(fileURLType) {
                        handleFiles(content: content, attachment: attachment, index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleFiles (content: NSExtensionItem, attachment: NSItemProvider, index: Int) {
        attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: fileURLType, options: nil) { [weak self] data, error in

            if error == nil, let url = data as? URL, let this = self {

                // Always copy
                let fileName = this.getFileName(from :url, type: .file)
                let newPath = FileManager.default
                    .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: this.appGroupId)!
                    .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                let copied = this.copyFile(at: url, to: newPath)
                if (copied) {
                    this.sharedMedia.append(SharedMediaFile(path: newPath.absoluteString, thumbnail: nil, duration: nil, type: .file))
                }

                if index == (content.attachments?.count)! - 1 {
                    let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: this.appGroupId)
                    userDefaults?.set(this.toData(data: this.sharedMedia), forKey: this.sharedKey)
                    userDefaults?.synchronize()
                    this.redirectToHostApp(type: .file)
                }

            } else {
                self?.dismissWithError()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
        return []
    }
    
    override func didSelectPost() {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
    
        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
        //self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
        print("didSelectPost");
    }
    
    private func dismissWithError() {
        print("[ERROR] Error loading data!")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Error loading data", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Error", style: .cancel) { _ in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    private func redirectToHostApp(type: RedirectType) {
        //ids may not loaded yet so we need loadIds here too
        loadIds();
        let url = URL(string: "ShareMedia-\(hostAppBundleIdentifier)://dataUrl=\(sharedKey)#\(type)")
        var responder = self as UIResponder?
        let selectorOpenURL = sel_registerName("openURL:")

        while (responder != nil) {
            if (responder?.responds(to: selectorOpenURL))! {
                let _ = responder?.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
            }
            responder = responder!.next
        }
        extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    enum RedirectType {
        case media
        case text
        case file
    }

    func getExtension(from url: URL, type: SharedMediaType) -> String {
        let parts = url.lastPathComponent.components(separatedBy: ".")
        var ex: String? = nil
        if (parts.count > 1) {
            ex = parts.last
        }

        if (ex == nil) {
            switch type {
                case .image:
                    ex = "PNG"
                case .video:
                    ex = "MP4"
                //TODO: Mirar si lo cambio por pdf
                case .file:
                    ex = "PDF"
            }
        }
        return ex ?? "Unknown"
    }

    func getFileName(from url: URL, type: SharedMediaType) -> String {
        var name = url.lastPathComponent

        if (name.isEmpty) {
            name = UUID().uuidString + "." + getExtension(from: url, type: type)
        }

        return name
    }

    func copyFile(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) -> Bool {
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dstURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstURL)
            }
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
        } catch (let error) {
            print("Cannot copy item at \(srcURL) to \(dstURL): \(error)")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    private func getSharedMediaFile(forVideo: URL) -> SharedMediaFile? {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: forVideo)
        let duration = (CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) * 1000).rounded()
        let thumbnailPath = getThumbnailPath(for: forVideo)

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: thumbnailPath.path) {
            return SharedMediaFile(path: forVideo.absoluteString, thumbnail: thumbnailPath.absoluteString, duration: duration, type: .video)
        }

        var saved = false
        let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        //        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        assetImgGenerate.maximumSize =  CGSize(width: 360, height: 360)
        do {
            let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(600, preferredTimescale: Int32(1.0)), actualTime: nil)
            try UIImage.pngData(UIImage(cgImage: img))()?.write(to: thumbnailPath)
            saved = true
        } catch {
            saved = false
        }

        return saved ? SharedMediaFile(path: forVideo.absoluteString, thumbnail: thumbnailPath.absoluteString, duration: duration, type: .video) : nil

    }

    private func getThumbnailPath(for url: URL) -> URL {
        let fileName = Data(url.lastPathComponent.utf8).base64EncodedString().replacingOccurrences(of: "==", with: "")
        let path = FileManager.default
            .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroupId)!
            .appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).jpg")
        return path
    }

    class SharedMediaFile: Codable {
        var path: String; // can be image, video or url path. It can also be text content
        var thumbnail: String?; // video thumbnail
        var duration: Double?; // video duration in milliseconds
        var type: SharedMediaType;


        init(path: String, thumbnail: String?, duration: Double?, type: SharedMediaType) {
            self.path = path
            self.thumbnail = thumbnail
            self.duration = duration
            self.type = type
        }

        // Debug method to print out SharedMediaFile details in the console
        func toString() {
            print("[SharedMediaFile] \n\tpath: \(self.path)\n\tthumbnail: \(self.thumbnail)\n\tduration: \(self.duration)\n\ttype: \(self.type)")
        }
    }

    enum SharedMediaType: Int, Codable {
        case image
        case video
        case file
    }

    func toData(data: [SharedMediaFile]) -> Data {
        let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(data)
        return encodedData!
    }

}

extension Array {
    subscript (safe index: UInt) -> Element? {
        return Int(index) < count ? self[Int(index)] : nil
    }
}
```

**pods/podfile**

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), _FILE_)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(_FILE_))
  
  # Sharing Extension is name of Extension which you created. It is 'Share Extension' and 'Sharing Extension' in example
  target 'Share Extension' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

This is the configuration of the App Groups on the capabilities tab and of the build settings (Both, Runner and Share Exception, are at the same group: group.xxxx)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And i was testing my app in the emulator iPhone 14 Pro - iOS 16.2.

I really appreciate if anyone can help me with this problem.

**Edit:**

The error occurs here. It seems that the container directory associated with the app group id is nil (The variable this.appGroupId is instantiated at this point).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved it. The problem was i added the app groups to Runner and Share Extension just for release mode, not for debug mode.